# What packages are not needed to run Ubuntu-Desktop?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, startup-applications

Is there a list of packages which i can uninstall but still have a simple desktop?

I don't need any of the additional packages being usually installed. Just the file manager and that's it.

Comment: First clearly define __needs__. That is subjective. What I consider __need__ may be bloat to you. That's why you must first clearly define where is your threshold. Otherwise this question can be closed as stated in the Faq.

Comment: And clarify the meaning of "Not needed to run Ubuntu". What do you mean by this? apport is part of Ubuntu,Zietgiest is part of it too. Those are needed to run a standard Ubuntu desktop. So, clear on What do you think an "Ubuntu" is.

Comment: Nobody can answer this but you. What you need is not what others need. Basically, the simplest answer is to start removing the application packages you don't need, and apt will tell you what packages will also be removed when you specify something to remove. When that list starts including things that you need, or which Ubuntu needs to run the basic underlying system, then those things are definitely required. Otherwise, this is really just an open-ended question and will again be closed as opinion based.

Comment: I disagree. the way this is worded is perfectly answerable. The criteria is: he want to be able to run Nautilus.   And xamiro: please stick to what you want to ask, don't add personal opinion  to a question ;-)

Comment: No. The question doesn't specify Nautilus. It just says file manager. For all we know, nautilus is too bloated.

Comment: "the" filemanager is Nautilus.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a list of packages which i can uninstall but still have a simple desktop?

No. But it should not be too hard to accomplish.

> I don't need any of the additional packages being usually installed. Just the file manager and that's it.

I see 2 approaches how you can manage this ..

1. start from a desktop install.

   Open Ubuntu Software Center and find and remove the installed software based on categories. That might leave some libraries.
    
   Do not use the advanced feature and uninstall Python and stuff like that; just applications. Also make sure not to delete the device driver.
2. Start from a system with no desktop.

   Use a minimal install version or the server install or your current desktop system where you remove the desktop.

   And then install nautilus (I assume you meant Nautilus but you can also pick another file manager or even a command line file manager and skip out on the whole desktop; like midnight commander as dobey suggested). It will install anything that is mandatory for that filemanager to run. Including the parts you need for the desktop to run if needed.

Comment: Or just start from a minimal or server install and only install `mc`. Who needs X and graphics drivers just for a file manager? All that bloat.

Comment: looks good to me too.